# How to configure rsync to sync locally 2 folders

Tags: rsync

I am doing some development on an Angular 2 (Typescript) + Laravael app, and I have the angular2 source files in my /resources/assets in Laravel. The typescript compiler works very well, but after it compiles, I would like that all my source folder to be copied to /public, so I can expose it with Laravel. I know that I can set in the .tsconfig file an output directory, but this is not an option, because the app is more complex. So, I need to synchronize `/resources/assets/app` with `/public/app`. How can I do this with rsync? if I type:

```
rsync -avzh /path-to-project/resources/assets/app-partner/ /path-to-project/public/app-partner/
```

it works perfectly, but I would like to launch this command as a daemon. I read tens of tutorials on how to set rsync as a daemon, but when i comes to configuring /etc/rsyncd.conf, I don't see where I can set the source and destination folders that I want to sync. Could anyone help me with a basic example? Or at least point me to the right direction?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The rsync daemon is not what you want (it sets up an FTP-like server for distributing to remote clients).

If you want continuous sync then there are several options, but it varies by OS and you don't say what you're using.

Assuming Linux, then I'd recommend `lsyncd`. It's a wrapper for rsync that watches a directory for changes and then triggers rsync when something happens.

Comment: I am using Mac,  and I have already tried using lsyncd, but apparently it doesn't get along with some low-level file system events from Max OSX, I have the problem described here: https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd/issues/384, and the author descourages using lsyncd under Mac, so I am looking for an alternative.